# Hiding unused public methods in an Android Library

Tags: android, methods, annotations, public

I am creating a library of Android function that I will use across a series of app I am creating.
I am using Android Studio to create these apps.

I have added three methods to the library. These methods are not used by the library, just the apps that use the library. While the apps still compile and work fine, I am very particular about getting warning in the source code. I know about the @SupressWarning("unused") annotation, but that only works on private methods, and will not work for me due to the fact that the methods, being in a library, need to be public.

Is there a way I can suppress the unused warnings in my source for a public method? I guess you could say that I find a small amount of comfort when I see the green arrow in Android Studio, showing me I have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a solution, not sure if it is the correct/best solution. I created a constructor in the class that calls each of the member methods. This eliminates the warnings in the editor.

```
package com.phoenixhosman.phoenixlib;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import static android.view.View.inflate;

public class ActivityPhoenixLib extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * While not needed, this constructor makes calls to the member method of the class
     * to clear errors in the editor.
     */
    ActivityPhoenixLib() {
        String dummy = InputDialog(this,"");
        if (dummy.equals("test")) {
            Error(this, "", false);
            Success(this,"",0);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * This method displays a dialog box with an error message and a close button.
     * @param strError the error message to display
     */
    public void Error(Context context, @NotNull String strError, Boolean exit) {
        if (strError.equals("")) {
            return;
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View view = inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_error, null);
        Button btnExit = view.findViewById(R.id.btnExitButton);
        Button btnError = view.findViewById(R.id.btnErrorMessage);
        btnError.setText(strError);
        mBuilder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (exit) System.exit(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method displays a dialog box with a message and a close button.
     * It also has an auto close function to auto close after a specified number of seconds.
     * @param strMessage the message to display
     */
    public void Success(Context context, @NotNull String strMessage, Integer autoclose) {
        if (strMessage.equals("")) {
            return;
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View view = inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_success, null);
        Button btnExit = view.findViewById(R.id.btnButton);
        Button btnError = view.findViewById(R.id.btnMessage);
        btnError.setText(strMessage);
        mBuilder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());
        new Handler().postDelayed(dialog::dismiss, autoclose * 1000);
    }

    /**
     * This method show an input box to get string input from the user.
     * @param strPrompt - the dialog prompt
     */
    public String InputDialog(Context context, @NotNull String strPrompt) {
        if (strPrompt.equals("")) {
            return "";
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final String[] retval = new String[1];
        View view = inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_input, null);
        TextView txtPrompt = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrompt);
        EditText edtLockPass = view.findViewById(R.id.edtLockPass);
        Button btnEnter = view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        txtPrompt.setText(getString(R.string.input_prompt, strPrompt));
        mBuilder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (edtLockPass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                retval[0] = "";
            } else {
                retval[0] = edtLockPass.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        dialog.dismiss();
        return retval[0];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve my results?